# show an array of the highest to lowest with column it belongs to from another table

Tags: mysql, query

I have two tables, one for suppliers_list and the other for purchase_orders. I want a query on the suppliers_list table to get the list of suppliers_id and suppliers_cat with a while loop and another query for the second table purchase_orders to get the count of column po_id from the purchase_orders table where suppliers_id in suppliers_list table is equals to suppliers_id in purchase_orders order by the highest count of column po_id. On the purchase_orders table, there is no suppliers_cat column and I want the output to show an array of the highest to lowest with it supplier_cat. Below are my two tables

```
suppliers_list TABLE

suppiers_id   suppliers_cat  
-----------   -------------
    1              A
    2              A
    3              B
    4              C
    5              D
    6              C


purchase_orders
 TABLE

po_id         suppliers_id  
-----------   -------------
    1              1
    2              1
    3              2
    4              3
    5              4
    6              5
```

I want the output to be like below:

```
C - 2
A - 2
D - 1
B - 1
```

From above you can see that it shows from highest to lowest with their suppliers_cat first then the count of po_id which is how many times it shows on the table.